# Unable to set cookies ASP.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, html

I am currently doing a project in which i have an asp.net core web api being called from a separate domain front end.

So I have implemented a JWT Token generator to let the user login, and I wanted to try saving the token through cookies and enable cookie authentication.

And here's my code for adding the cookie, it is in my middleware code

```
//Add the cookies for login
CookieOptions options = new CookieOptions();
options.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5);
context.Response.Cookies.Append("access_token", encodedJwt, options);
```

But I am running into some trouble saving the cookie itself.

[image: responds cookie]
and you can see in the image the cookie is return but it is being saved

[image: Getting all cookies stored that is not HTTPCookie]

and inspecting fiddler i can see my set cookie code which i dont see any issue but i am really new to cookies  so i might be wrong

```
Set-Cookie: access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJsb2xzcGFtbWVyQG91dGxvb2suY29tIiwianRpIjoiN2FkNWI0MTktOGNhZC00MzZmLWJjZTQtZjM3ZmI5MjgxNWU2IiwiaWF0Ijo3OTAsIm5iZiI6MTUwMTgzODg5MiwiZXhwIjoxNTAxOTI1MjkyLCJpc3MiOiJFeGFtcGxlSXNzdWVyIiwiYXVkIjoiRXhhbXBsZUF1ZGllbmNlIn0.gA4yZgs2r3OJqSYWlUxaV7bkGcP5YdN1fcplMzZT868; expires=Fri, 04 Aug 2017 09:33:12 GMT; path=/
```

And i try multiple browser like google chrome, ff and opera but no luck.
I even hosted my website thinking maybe it is because it is running on local as I have read some article online saying it is the issue but no luck

If anyone has the answer to my solution please tell me, and Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to set a cookie from your API? Typically API's use bearer authentication where each request includes the JWT in the `Authorization` header of the request

Comment: @Jamiec yea but instead of using bearer token i am trying to use cookies instead, i have declared it in my Startup.cs. And it works, i tried it with fiddler but I can't seem to the cookie to set in my browser

Comment: might give up trying to set the cookie in the server and set it in the frontend instead if I can't find a solution soon

Comment: Its not always a browser that will be calling your API. Calls will be headless - ie, there will be nothing to store/send the cookies. I might be wrong, but I dont think this is possible

Comment: where you able to solve this? I have the same problem right now

Comment: @AlejandroB. Sorry bro, i couldn't i just use jjs Cookie and add the cookie in the front-end